# avoid specifying functions to call in diamond design

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

I have a diamond design currently, and I saw a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064880/diamond-problem)

In that question, let me assume that class B and class C are virtual inherited from Class A, so in Class D, when we need to call virtual functions, we need to specify which one needed to call.

```
D::foo()
{
  B::foo(); //specify foo() in B
}
```

For my diamond design, I have a lot of virtual functions to rewrite, in order to let these functions called by correct B or C father class functions.

It is not good, a lot of repeated work need to be done, when I have child class, do you have some better solutions, so that I can call foo() of B in class D but no rewrite for the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++11, you can do an aliasing:

```
class A
{
    public:
        virtual void foo() { cout << "A" << endl; }
}


class B : public virtual A
{
    public:
        void foo() { cout << "B" << endl; }
}


class C : public virtual A
{
    public:
        void foo() { cout << "C" << endl; }
}

class D : public B, C
{
    using B::foo;
}
```

This way, doin:

```
D obj;
obj.foo();
```

Will output `B`;

Answer (score -3):

I think template classes might do the trick here.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/

Comment: How should it help here?

Comment: then again, reading the problem again seems I thought you try to address the problem which you have many inheriting classes, D1,D2 etc and some use A and some use B. Or the case when A and Black have different specified roles for each of them.