# Catch all Class Exceptions

Tags: c++, class, exception

I am trying to give the user the option to catch all the errors from my class or to catch them individually. I can catch individual exceptions but I can't catch it correctly when I try to catch the base error class. I get the standard error from std::exception "Unknown Error".

I have tried to catch the base exception and to catch the derived errors.

Can I have all my errors be a base error type and catch them all as such?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

struct FooException 
    : public std::exception
{

};

struct FooRuntimeException
    : public std::runtime_error,
    public FooException
{
    FooRuntimeException(const char* what)
        : runtime_error(what) {}

};

struct FooRangeError
    : public std::range_error, 
    public FooException
{
    FooRangeError(const char* what)
        : range_error(what) {}
};


class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    ~Foo() {};

    void throwRunTimeException()
    {
        throw FooRuntimeException("Runtime Error");
    }
    void throwRangeError()
    {
        throw FooRuntimeException("Range Error");
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        auto foo = Foo();
        foo.throwRunTimeException();
    }
    catch (const FooException &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what(); // catches standard error message
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Is there a way to do this or is templates a possibility?

Comment: None of your derived classes initialise their `FooException` subobject. Why the multiple inheritance?

Comment: There really is no possible reason for using multiple inheritance when it comes to exceptions.

Comment: Are you enjoying shooting yourself in the foot?

Comment: You are forcing a [diamond problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064880/diamond-problem). Your exceptions inherit from `std::exception` twice.

Comment: I mean they only default-initialise them, of course.

Comment: Either 1) do not derive `FooRuntimeException` from `std::runtime_error` and `FooRangeError` from `std::range_error`, just derive them from `FooException` only, or 2) do not derive `FooException` from `std::exception`, since `std::runtime_error` and `std::range_error` already derive from it.

Comment: @NeilButterworth -- many years go, Jerry Schwarz (author of the iostreams library) gave me a $10 prize for pointing out that when you're writing a library that uses two other libraries, each with its own exception hierarchy, it could make sense to merge exceptions from those libraries into a new, single hierarchy with each exception in the new hierarchy inheriting from one exception from each of the two base libraries. He said this was the first **legitimate** use of multiple inheritance that he had heard of. That's not this case, of course.

Comment: @Pete As iostreams itself uses multiple inheritance, are you saying Jerry Schwarz didn't think its use was legitimate? I myself would never design an MI hierarchy, particularly for things like exceptions that I believe should be kept as simple as possible, for obvious reasons. But I have used libraries that seemed to use MI quite  elegantly, for example (long while ago) the Reuters Triarch trading data system.

Comment: @NeilButterworth — yes, that was the implication: that the use of multiple inheritance in iostreams was gratuitous. And I forgot to mention: that was before the standard had its own exception hierarchy. Multiple inheritance in exception hierarchies today would lead to problems when someone properly writes a catch clause to catch `const std::exception&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting confused because there are two base classes of type `std::exception` in each of your exception classes. Try catching `const std::exception&` and watch the compiler complain.

The actual problem that you're getting here is that the code explicitly initializes one of those bases, but default-initializes the other; the catch clause gets the `FooException` object, which has the default-initialized `std::exception`, so that's the message you get.

As some of the comments have hinted, this is a complicated class hierarchy, and there's not much you can do to fix the problem. To avoid having multiple copies of `std::exception` you'd need to inherit **virtually** from `std::exception` in the two places where it's used. The inheritance in `FooException` is easily changed, but you can't change the fact that `std::runtime_exception` is not derived virtually from `std::exception`.

So there's a design problem, and you have to decide exactly what you want to provide to the user. This hierarchy does more than what you describe in your question, since it provides **both** `FooException` **and** parts of the standard exception hierarchy. Pick one: either use the standard exception hierarchy, or use your own exception hierarchy, with `FooException` deriving from `std::exception` and providing a constructor that initializes the `std::exception` sub-object.

Comment: Also, there's a hack that could make this work, but I don't want to put it into the answer because that would imply that it's a good idea. Change `FooException` so that it doesn't derive from `std::exception`, and make its destructor (or any other member function) virtual. Then you can catch `const FooException& ex` and use `dynamic_cast<const std::exception&>(ex)` to get to the `std::exception` sub-object.

Comment: Do you have a website or book you would recommend? I would like to understand the advantage of my own exception hierarchy more.